# Postfix / mailutils Mail appears to be sent in logs, but not in the mailbox

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I've seen few of this question here but I couldn't find a solution for it.

I'm currently trying to set up Postfix with mailtutils, but I can't see my incoming emails in my mailbox, so I am not sure if there is something wrong in the process.

The mails I sent to my mail account appear to be sent in the logs as delivered but they are not received into the mailbox, not even the spam folder. The logs are not displaying any error, so I am not sure what is the problem.

Below is the output emails log:

**mail.log**

```
Jan 12 18:01:19 mail postfix/qmgr[25826]: 69C03AE5FF7: from=<myname@mycompanyname.com.au>, size=366, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 12 18:01:19 mail postfix/local[25873]: 69C03AE5FF7: to=<myname@mycompanyname.com.au>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jan 12 18:01:19 mail postfix/qmgr[25826]: 69C03AE5FF7: removed
```

Below is the main configuration file:

**main.cf**

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mycompanyname.com.au
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mycompanyname.com.au, mail.mycompanyname.com, localhost.$myhostname, localhost
# uncomment this if you don't wanna send external emails that are not "mycompanyname"
#relayhost = [mycompanyname.com.au]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

#local_transport = virtual
#virtual_transport = mailutils
```

I also setup the `sasl_passwd` with the correct credentials and I am using the following command to send email:

```
echo  "body of your email" | mail -s "This is a subject" -a "From:myname@mycompanyname.com.au" myname@gmail.com
```

The problem is that I was able to send and receive emails from @mycompanyname.com.au to @outlook.com, @gmail.com and @hotmail.com even to my university mailbox and I can see the emails delivered in the mailbox, but the emails are not shown in the "mycompany" mailbox. For example, if I send from @mycompanyname.com.au to @mycompany.com.au nothing appears. Which indicates that the email are send but not received perhaps?

The logs output are not displaying any problem, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Note that I am using outlook web app to receive emails for "mycompanyname" server and I made sure it is not filtering spam emails.

Answer (score 0):

By default `postfix` delivers mail to a local mailbox in `/var/mail/user` or `/var/spool/mail/user` on the server where `postfix` is running. If you want to receive your emails in an "outlook web app" you need to configure `postfix` to deliver messages there.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do that? I appreciate your answer